# ASP.NET LinqDataSource "OnUpdating" method not update value to null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, telerik, linqdatasource

I have asp.net page with a linqdatasource, it use the OnUpdating method.

```
OnUpdating="Entity_OnUpdating"
```

In code-behind:

```
protected void Entity_OnUpdating(object sender, LinqDataSourceUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    MyClass objEntity = (MyClass)e.NewObject;
    if (expression)
        MyClass.InfoID = Guid.NewGuid();
    else
        MyClass.InfoID = null;
}
```

If the `expression` is false, and `MyClass.InfoID` was not null before update, `MyClass.InfoID` not changes to null.

UPD:
`MyClass` has two fields: 
1) `ID` - primary key, 
2) `InfoID` - nullable foreign key.

Do you know, why it work like this?

Answer (score 0):

What does your MyClass object looks like? Without looking at the object, I can guess that the property 'ID' is either listed as Primary key, Foreign Key, or simply does not allow nulls.

Answer (score 0):

I think type of `InfoID` property is `Guid` which is not nullable, so when you are trying to assign a null value to it, it is not accepting.

Change the type of `InfoID` property to `Nullable<Guid>` and it would work.